# Sideloaded MAUI app requires Administrative Privilege

Tags: .net, maui, winui-3, msix

I have code signed (3rd Party) and published a .NET Maui app for Windows in a business environment (Side Loaded LOB). The MSIX installer generated installs onto PC's without error, but I've noticed the application won't start unless the user is part of the Administrators group on the PC. The application will open and function if it ran as administrator (prompts User Access Control dialog).

My question is if this is normal behavior or is their something missing from my appxmanifest that would address this issue?

Edit: What has become even more strange is this is inconsistent. I have 2 of 7 PC's (all with users not in Administrators Group) exhibiting this error. All workstations are up to date on Windows Updates / Features. One PC is giving me something in the event log (not all the time).

[image]

Below are snippets of my appxmanifest

```
<Capabilities>
    <rescap:Capability Name="runFullTrust" />
    <Capability Name="internetClient"/>
</Capabilities>

  <Dependencies>
    <TargetDeviceFamily Name="Windows.Universal" MinVersion="10.0.17763.0" MaxVersionTested="10.0.19041.0" />
    <TargetDeviceFamily Name="Windows.Desktop" MinVersion="10.0.17763.0" MaxVersionTested="10.0.19041.0" />
  </Dependencies>

  <Resources>
    <Resource Language="x-generate" />
  </Resources>

  <Applications>
    <Application Id="App" Executable="$targetnametoken$.exe" EntryPoint="$targetentrypoint$">
      <uap:VisualElements
        DisplayName="$placeholder$"
        Description="$placeholder$"
        Square150x150Logo="$placeholder$.png"
        Square44x44Logo="$placeholder$.png"
        BackgroundColor="transparent">
        <uap:DefaultTile Square71x71Logo="$placeholder$.png" Wide310x150Logo="$placeholder$.png" Square310x310Logo="$placeholder$.png" />
        <uap:SplashScreen Image="$placeholder$.png" />
      </uap:VisualElements>
    </Application>
  </Applications>
```

app.manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<assembly manifestVersion="1.0" xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
  <assemblyIdentity version="1.0.0.0" name="someapp.WinUI.app"/>

  <application xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
    <windowsSettings>
      <!-- The combination of below two tags have the following effect:
           1) Per-Monitor for >= Windows 10 Anniversary Update
           2) System < Windows 10 Anniversary Update
      -->
      <dpiAware xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SMI/2005/WindowsSettings">true/PM</dpiAware>
      <dpiAwareness xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SMI/2016/WindowsSettings">PerMonitorV2, PerMonitor</dpiAwareness>
    </windowsSettings>
  </application>
</assembly>
```

Any insight on this would be appreciated.